# SKSceneにUIButtonを追加(addSubview)しても表示されないのはなぜか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

■バージョン
swift 4

■やりたいこと/質問
MenuPageScene.swift（下記に詳細を記載）にUIButtonを追加したい
現状下記コードでは追加できていない状況です。
追加したいのですが、下記コードに問題があるのか、そのほかの設定等で失念していることがあるのか、swift4ではできないのかがわかりません。
ご回答お待ちしております。
.sksファイルとの連携はできており、MenuPageScene.sksにColor Spriteを
追加するとシミュレータに表示されます。MenuPageScene.sksのCustom Classには
MenuPageSceneを設定しています。

■ファイル構成
MenuPageViewController.swift
MenuPageScene.swift
MenuPageScene.sks:CustomeClassにMenuPageSceneを設定

■ソースコード
MenuPageViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class MenuPageViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MenuPageScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
・・・以下省略
```

MenuPageScene.swift

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit
class MenuPageScene: SKScene{

    let myButton = UIButton()

    @objc func onClickMyButton(sender : UIButton){

        let rect = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:50.0,y:50.0),size:CGSize(width:50.0,height:50.0)) )
        rect.fillColor = UIColor.red
        //rect.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.midX, self.frame.midY)
        rect.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width:50.0,height:50.0))

        self.addChild(rect)

    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // ボタンを生成.
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        myButton.setTitle("Add Block", for: UIControlState.normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        myButton.setTitle("Done", for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        myButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: -self.view!.frame.width/4, y:-self.view!.frame.height/4)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickMyButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view!.addSubview(myButton);
    }
・・・以下省略
}
```

Comment: MenuPageScene.swiftにてUIKitをインポートし忘れていました。コンパイルエラーにならなかったので問題ないと思っていますが、念のため追記いたします。上記質問のソースコードにimport UIKitを追加しました。

Comment: MenuPageScene.swift内でskshapenodeオブジェクトを生成すると反映されて表示されることも確認済みです。

Comment: デフォルトのGameテンプレートのGameScene.swiftにUIButtonを追加するコードを記載しても表示されないことを確認しました。swift4でサポートされないということでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- あなたのコードは不要なセミコロン`;`の位置からして「spritekit ボタン」と言ったキーワードで上位に出てくるあるサイトのコードを元にしているように思われるのですが? 参考にしたサイトがある場合、リンク等で出典を明示した方が早く問題の解決に結びつく場合が多いです。
- あなたはそのコードで普通のViewにボタンを追加できるかどうか試されたでしょうか。(`SKScene`の表示を受け持っている)`SKView`にボタンを追加するコードは、普通にプログラムでViewにボタンを追加するコードと変わりません。まずは普通のViewにボタンを追加できるようなコードにしてください。
- あなたのコード内のコメントで「ボタンを生成」と書いてある場所では、ボタンを生成しておらず、実際にボタンを「生成」しているのは、プロパティの初期化式の中です。

  ```
  let myButton = UIButton()
  ```

  `UIButton`クラスでは引数を取らないイニシャライザ`init()`の動作は明確には定義されていません。
  [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) > [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) > [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton)

  ドキュメントで動作の定義された次の3つのイニシャライザのどれかを使った方が良いでしょう。
  [`init(frame:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622488-init), [`init?(coder:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622477-init), [`init(type:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624028-init)
  (ただし、2個目を普通のアプリから呼ぶことはまずあり得ない。)

  ちなみに`UIButton()`とすると(現在のiOSでは)サイズが0のボタンができてしまい、当然見えません。
- あなたのコード内のこの行:

  ```
  myButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: -self.view!.frame.width/4, y:-self.view!.frame.height/4)
  ```

  `layer.position`で表示位置を調整するのは特殊な事例である上に、原点(Viewの場合、画面の左上隅)よりも左上を指定しているので、よほど大きなサイズのボタンでないと見えません。

---

と言うわけであなたの現在のコードは、

### サイズが0のボタンを画面の外に置く

と言う動作をするものになっています。

`SKScene`の中でやっているかどうかは別にして、それでは表示されるはずがありません。

---

SpriteKitの画面内に`UIButton`を置くなんてデザインが本当に良い事かどうかの判断は置いて、画面の中に大きさのある`UIButton`を置くなら、例えばこんな感じのコードになります。

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // 画面の中央に
    let x = view.frame.width/2 - 100
    let y = view.frame.height/2 - 20
    // サイズが(200,40)のボタンを生成.
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 200, height: 40))

    myButton.backgroundColor = .red
    myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    myButton.setTitle("Add Block", for: .normal)
    myButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    myButton.setTitle("Done", for: .highlighted)
    myButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)
    myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClickMyButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(myButton)
}
```

Comment: そのあたりの仕様を理解できておりませんでした。もっとドキュメントを漁って見ます。ありがとうございました。